# HBase: Zookeeper serves Internal IP to Remote client (Java API)

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am running a very basic HBase connection program from a remote server. 
Reading the server logs, I see Zookeeper acknowledge the request, but then serves to the Client the internal IP of HBase Master, which is of no use from the outside world.

I know where the master is and what its public IP is but I do not know how to effectively connect to HBase remotely using the Java API. Any ideas ?

I've seen some people advice to mess up with the /etc/hosts file but that's an ugly and inelegant solution, and it breaks other parts of the ecosystem.

```
    String zookeeperHost = "public.ip.address";

    Configuration hconfig = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    hconfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum",zookeeperHost);
    hconfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
    hconfig.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure");


    HBaseAdmin.available(hconfig);
```

> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException:
> com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: 
> java.net.UnknownHostException: unknown host: ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.internal